# How to use protobuf with proguard

Tags: java, proguard, protobuf-java

After adding **protobuf** dependency to a project that is using **proguard** for releases I run into the following issues:

```
Warning: ***.***.Api: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor getDescriptor()' in library class com.google.protobuf.AnyProto
Warning: ***.***.Api$Information: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder toBuilder()' in library class com.google.protobuf.Any
Warning: ***.***.Api$Information: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder mergeFrom(com.google.protobuf.Any)' in library class com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder
Warning: ***.***.Api$Information: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Any buildPartial()' in library class com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder
Warning: ***.***.Api$Information$Builder: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Any build()' in library class com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder
Warning: ***.***.Api$Information$Builder: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder mergeFrom(com.google.protobuf.Any)' in library class com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder
Warning: ***.***.Api$Information$Builder: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Any buildPartial()' in library class com.google.protobuf.Any$Builder
Warning: ***.***Service: can't find referenced method 'com.google.protobuf.Any pack(com.google.protobuf.Message)' in library class com.google.protobuf.Any
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was that another dependency already had a transitive dependency on `protobuf-javalite` and it conflicted with the `protobuf-java` I was adding.

As per https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/8104#issuecomment-887076083:

> protobuf-java and protobuf-javalite should
> never be included in the same project [...]  if you're using Gradle, we
> recommend an approach like this:
> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps
>
> Telling the system to exclude protobuf-javalite because you explicitly
> depend on protobuf-java is technically OK, but this might have
> negative side effects to performance or code size on mobile platforms,
> it also might be totally fine for you, your mileage may vary.

The problem was solved for me after excluding `protobuf-javalite` like this

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-javalite'
}
```